# Use array in where clause not working

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a query in php file which is used to filter the data in file from mysql database

```
$_SESSION['sc_session'][$this->Ini->sc_page]['grid_deposit']['where_orig'] = " where Reg_no = \"69\"";
```

In this line if Reg_no = \"69\"" , if i change the 69 to any value data is being modified but if i use an array instead of 69 then its not working like this

```
   $_SESSION['sc_session'][$this->Ini->sc_page]['grid_deposit']['where_orig'] = " where Reg_no = " . $fc . "";
```

But if i use
    $fc = 69;
    echo $fc;

Then its working but not on that line please tell me how to code this The error on which i get is

```
Error 
Error while accessing the database:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
select count(*) from deposit where Reg_no =
```

Comment: What is `$fc`? Post the `var_dump()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your Reg_no =\"69\""

and your Reg_no =". $fc."";

are you not missing the "" of the $fc

```
   $_SESSION['sc_session'][$this->Ini->sc_page]['grid_deposit']['where_orig'] = " where Reg_no = \"" . $fc . "\"";
```

to match your 69 example.

Comment: and the error is the exact same thing? then the $fc is being lost on its way to that query.
what happens when you output $_SESSION['sc_session'][$this->Ini->sc_page]['grid_deposit']['where_orig'] directly after setting $fc
and is the query ran after this line...if it doesnt then its being lost before you hit the query.

Comment: but actually i have this array on other file

Answer (score 1):

In your original question you stated this error text

```
Error 
Error while accessing the database:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
select count(*) from deposit where Reg_no =
```

If the $fc would be an array you would see this in the query as such. If i remember correctly it would look like that ...

```
Error 
Error while accessing the database:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
select count(*) from deposit where Reg_no = Array
```

As it does not i assume that the variable $fc is empty. Did you check the variable or better create the query and log it somewhere to check the query as it gets sent to the sql server.

As mentioned, if it would be an array PHP would convert it when wrongly used to the text "Array" which you should find in the query.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you try to do something like

"where Reg_no IN (".implode(",", $fc).")";

Comment: Error 
Error while accessing the database:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
select count(*) from deposit where Reg_no IN ()